# How does one parse strings in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, scanf

I have a file that contains lines as below:

```
25 1 0 0 0 0
27 1 0 0 0 0
20 0 0 0 0 0
32 1 0 0 0 0
23 1 0 0 0 0
16 0 0 0 0 0
28 1 0 0 0 0
```

First,  I store each line with value=1 in the second column as element of a string array.  I call the stored elements back via a for-loop, and parse the contents of the element into integers. How does one do that in c++?

```
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
   .....
   .....
   .....
   .....
char line[100];
vector<string> vec_line;
string Vline;
int trimVal, compa, nil0, nil1, nil2, nil3;
  ......
  ......
  ......
//then store lines as strings in vec_line as required by the premise above
// after that, retrieve the contents of the elements of the vector
for (int iline=0; iline<vec_line.size(); iline++) {
   cout<<"iline  "<<iline<<"  vec_line[iline]";
   //then I want to parse contents of each string element and store them integer formats
   sscanf(vec_line[iline], "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &trimVal, &compa, &nil0, &nil1, &nil2, &nil3); //how would one do this simple parsing task in c and c++?
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
sscanf(vec_line[iline], "%d %d ...
```

as the first argument to [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) is a `const char*` and not a `std::string`. Change to:

```
sscanf(vec_line[iline].c_str(), "%d %d ...
```

Recommend checking the return value of `sscanf()` to ensure all expected assignments were made:

```
if (6 == sscanf(vec_line[iline].c_str(), "%d %d ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`sscanf` is a C function, since you are already using C++ streams to output (and presumably read from the file?) you are better off using a `stringstream` to convert between strings and data types.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   stringstream sstr;
   string mystr = "123";
   int i;

   sstr << mystr;

   sstr >> i;

   cout << i << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

will output `123` to stdout. Of course you can also read from an `ifstream` using the `>>` operator directly into an `int` or `double` if you wish.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I *needed* to store each row as a string, I'd do something more like this:

```
struct row { 
    static const int columns = 6;
    std::vector<int> column_data;

    // should we keep or ignore a row? Ignore if column 1 != 1.
    struct filter {
        bool operator()(row const &r) { return r.column_data[1] != 1; }
    };

    // read in a row.
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, row &r) {
        r.column_data.resize(row::columns);
        for (int i=0; i<row::columns; i++)
            is >> r.columns[i];
        return is;
    }

    // write a row out to a file.
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, row const &r) { 
        std::copy(r.column_data.begin(), r.column_data.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
        return os;
};
```

Then reading and displaying the data would look something like this:

```
std::vector<row> data;

std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<row>(input_file),
                    std::istream_iterator<row>(),
                    std::back_inserter(data),
                    row::filter());

std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<row>(output_file, "\n"));
```

Or, if you just want to copy the correct rows from some input file to some output file, you can use the correct iterators to do that directly:

```
std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<row>(input_file),
                    std::istream_iterator<row>(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<row>(output_file),
                    row::filter());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always lex and yacc (or [Flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) and [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/index.html))